# Option Based Portfolio Insurance OPBI Simulation Excel

Tags: portfolio, option-strategies, excel

I want to simulate an example of OBPI in Excel. I can't find any example online with random figures that show how to simulate it.

I tried to understand the appendix of Perold (1995): Dynamic Strategies for Asset Allocation
I shared the appendix with you. Kindly help me simulate the OBPI on excel with random settings (e.g. So=100, u=10%, o=20%, T=1, K=So=100 , r=5%)

Please could someone tell me, step by step, how and when to apply any formulas to get an OPBI simulation on Excel. [image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, its enough to simulate returns monthly.

Comment: I have a function which calculates the call under BlackScholes. I have understood the Black Scholes. The problem start after using Black Scholes. (First pic: I got it). The definition on the second picture is the problem. How should I proceed, after calculating the call using Black-Scholes-Merton?

Comment: Strike price is set at K=100, and how many options is the question.......

Comment: Nope. "$n$ and $K$ are *determined jointly* according to the following equations". I think your question is how to do this. Right? (I finally understood your question ?)

Comment: yes this is my question...